# in IE9 uploadFile is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

1 Add the file input box

```
<input type="file" id="uploadFile" ng-model="upFile" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this)" />
```

2 Create the setFile method in the controller

```
$scope.setFile = function (element) {
    $scope.uploadedFile = element.files[0];
}
```

as above,I use this way to upload file ,it works in FireFox  but in IE9 it shows that the "element is null our undefined". What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

`files` is a HTML5 file api feature and works only on browsers that support it.

It's not supported in IE9 see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi

You can check if `files` is supported before use it, try (not tested):

```
if( ev.target.files ){
  $scope.uploadedFile = element.files[0];
}else{
  $scope.uploadedFile = ev.target.value;
}
```

Comment: `ev.target.value` give you the file name, not the file.

Comment: No problem.  Note that there is no way to get the "file" client side in IE9 and older, since there is no File API support.  The best you can do submit the form containing the file input and deal with it server-side.

Comment: Or to use some components that do all the stuff for you (like fineuploader ;-)

Comment: " The best you can do submit the form containing the file input and deal with it server-side."i don't know  how to do.could you give me some examples？

Comment: It depends on your server side implementation (php, .net ?), my guess is to use a component to deal with file upload stuff like plupload, fineuploader, uploadify and others...